# GridLayout not evenly spacing children throughout screen

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, grid-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a GridLayout and inside it are 6 LinearLayout children. Inside those are buttons and other things.

In Android Studio it looks fine, however on an actual device (and even emulator) it does not space evenly. Here is a picture of what is happening.
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout <!--main layout stuff-->
>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="2">
        <!--
           there are six of these inside the grid layout
        -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:src="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

     </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in which device you testing?

Comment: HTC One Mini, Samsung, and emulator

Comment: I suggest you to use Gridview custom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with this is that `android:layout_columnWeight` and `android:layout_rowWeight` are new in Lollipop and so aren't supported before that. You can use [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) from the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout) and `app:layout_columnWeight`/`app:layout_rowWeight` to get these features for older android devices.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rowCount="4"
    app:columnCount="2">
        <!--
           there are six of these inside the grid layout
        -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:src="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the height and width of `LinearLayout` to `0dp` to match up to the parent layout
Checkout this one

```
<RelativeLayout <!--main layout stuff-->
>
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="2">
        <!--
           there are six of these inside the grid layout
        -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:src="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

     </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When I try that it looks perfect in Android Studio but when I run the app i just see white now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_bg"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

try `scaleType` to `fitXY` in your `ImageButton`

Comment: Nope. Now it is just showing the relative layout the grid children cannot be seen when i run the app